# python3 -m build gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathlib2'

Tags: python, build, pathlib

I am trying to build a Python package, but it gives the following error.

```
* Creating virtualenv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools >= 40.8.0, wheel)
* Getting dependencies for sdist...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 333, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 285, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return hook(config_settings)
  File "/tmp/build-env-eyqolcf7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
  File "/tmp/build-env-eyqolcf7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-eyqolcf7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 482, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
  File "/tmp/build-env-eyqolcf7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathlib2'

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
```

I have already installed pathlib2. What is the solution?

Comment: What does your `pip freeze` look like ?

Comment: @was1209 It has `pathlib2==2.3.7.post1`.

Comment: @was1209 There is no problem with `python setup.py install`, the only problem is with `python3 -m build`.

Comment: maybe you mean `python setup.py build`

Comment: maybe you have two Python installed and you installed module in one Python but now you run code with other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. Maybe you should use `python3 -m pip install ...` instead of `pip install ...`. OR maybe you have `pip3` and it may install for `python3`. Check if `pip -V` shows line with text `python3.10`

Comment: @furas might be right. 

Eftal mind looking at that ? Assuming you are not in a virtual environment

Comment: @furas @was1209 No, I am not in a virtual environment. I have checked every Python version in my system and all have `pathlib2==2.3.7.post1`. I have also tried to build with other Python versions but all of them give the same error.

Comment: error shows problem with `python3.10`  - so you should check `python3.10 -m pip freeze` to see if it has `pathlib2==2.3.7.post1`. But maybe it needs to add `pathlib2` somewhere to setup when you build package because it creates `virtualenv isolated environment...` and it may not copy `pathlib2` to this environment

Comment: @furas Yes, it has `pathlib2==2.3.7.post1`.

Comment: I have no idea what is the problem - and I can't test it. You may need to put all code on some server (ie, GitHub) and share link to full code.

Comment: @furas https://github.com/eftalgezer/fstring_to_format

Comment: The question should be updated with specific steps, OS versions, python versions, how you arrived at your starting point, steps you take after. Right now the only steps are whatever one can infer from the comments. I tried building on ubuntu just now, with Python 3.10.6, no issues whatsoever. I created a venv first to work out of... because that's what I do generally. My installation is completely fresh (docker ubuntu image with Python etc.). If you update your steps, maybe more folks can repro the issue you see... I and others cannot recreate the issue from what I see.

Answer (score 6):

In python 3.9, installing build module solved the problem (it was not there initially).

```
python -m pip install build
```

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully build this in `Python3.10`. `pip3.10 freeze` gave me this output

```
    build==0.8.0
    packaging==21.3
    pep517==0.13.0
    pyparsing==3.0.9
    tomli==2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation of the `build` package, it does not have a stable compatibility

https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#compatibility

You can try switching to an older version of python (3.9 recommended) and try again,
ideally, that should solve the error since in traceback, the error seems to originate from setuptools ( which will be automatically reverted back to an older version with a older python version )

NOTE: You will also need to reinstall build in the new python version

Let me know if you face any issues with it.